# In git, can I see only code which is common between 2 commits

Tags: git

Let's say I have a project with a long history:

```
0c13c1c - (HEAD) Change 4
fd2ea81 - Change 3
1b82694 - Change 2
5d7f469 - Change 1
b68482e - Initial commit
```

I know that *most* code has changed between 5d7f469 and 0c13c1c, but there is still some code which hasn't changed.

Can I do something like:

```
git common-code 5d7f469 0c13c1c > common-code-only.tar.gz
```

I would like common-code-only.tar.gz to contain a full project with only those lines of code which existed in 5d7f469 and still exist in 0c13c1c.

Comment: How do you define "common code"? That which is outside the patch hunks? If so, you'll need to write a program that everts the patch hunks. If you define it as "whole files that have not been changed", the problem gets easier (but you still need to write code).

Comment: By "common code" I mean code chunks which have not changed, let's say file A contains some lines which have not changed between two commits, only those lines would appear in the result. I guess it is like the opposite of a git diff.

Answer (score 1):

OK, based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502804/in-git-can-i-see-only-code-which-is-common-between-2-commits?noredirect=1#comment86208016_49502804):

As far as I know, you will need to write your own tool.  You could write your own "antidiff", consisting of a common subsequence finder plus code to print the common subsequences.  Existing `diff` tools run this same finder but then print the *different* parts.  Or, you can run `git diff` (or any other diff tool), which will tell you which parts are different.  By exclusion, the remainder of the files in question must be the same.  That's what I meant by "everting the patch hunks" in [my own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502804/in-git-can-i-see-only-code-which-is-common-between-2-commits?noredirect=1#comment86009723_49502804): turning the diff hunks ["inside out"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evert).

Note that Python has a library, [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html), that does common-subsequence finding.  If you prefer to write your own code, rather than everting diff output, the `difflib` code will make this a lot easier.